# When can $0$ be a dimension of $(V \cap W)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, vector-analysis, gre-exam

GRE [0568](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~cmarshak/GRE1.pdf)

---

[image]

---

GRE [1268](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~iacoley/gre/Practice%201.pdf)

---

[image]

---

Why is that $0$ is included in the former but not in the latter?

It seems to me we just use the rule:

$$\dim(V+W)=\dim(V)+\dim(W)-\dim(V \cap W) \le \dim(\text{Well in this case we have X or} \ \mathbb R^4)$$

---

What's up with [Rambotutoring's solution](https://web.archive.org/web/20150701191646/http://rambotutoring.com/GR0568-solutions.pdf) then?

---

[image]

---

Why doesn't the same argument apply to the latter?

Comment: Two $4$-dimensional subspaces of a $7$-dimensional space must overlap nontrivially (be at least $1$-dimensional).

Comment: @Surb Rambotutoring's argument for the 0568 problem does not exclude zero. Why can similar reasoning not apply to the 1268 problem?

Comment: @DavidP Thanks! Post as answer? I think so far you're the only who addressed the rambotutoring argument

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me answer the question "Why doesn't the same argument apply to the latter?".

The argument that is being talked about is "a minimum of $0$ elements (corresponding to the case where $V$ and $W$ are disjoint except for the zero vector)".

That cannot happen in the case of two $4$-dimensional subspaces of a $7$-dimensional vectorspace: their intersection has at least dimension $1$. This follows from the dimension formula you quote yourself: $\dim(V) + \dim(W) - \dim(V \cap W) \leq \dim(X)$, so $8 - \dim(V \cap W) \leq 7$.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there it is: in GRE 1268 we have

$$7=\dim X\ge\dim(V+W)=\dim V+\dim W-\dim(V\cap W)=8-\dim(V\cap W)\implies$$

$$\implies\dim(V\cap W)\ge8-7=1$$

but in GRE 0568 we have

$$4=\dim \Bbb R^4\ge\dim V+\dim W-\dim(V\cap W)=4-\dim(V\cap W)\implies$$

$$\implies \dim(V\cap W)\ge 0\;,\;\;\text{which is trivial, but also}$$

$$V\cap W\le V,\,W\implies \dim (V\cap W)\le\dim V=2$$

and from here the solution follows

Comment: Rambotutoring's argument for the 0568 problem does not exclude zero. Why can similar reasoning not apply to the 1268 problem?

Comment: @BCLC Read **carefully** the above answer and deduce *why* ! The *why* is there...

Comment: I understand the answer if we use the $\dim$ formula. I'm asking about Rambotutoring's argument

Comment: Rambout...whatever's, argument doesn't exclude zero because *it doesn't have to*. Observe though that it does restrict (because it **must**!) the dimension of the intersection to be two. Why? Clear...and also remarked in my answer above. He just mentions "being disjoint", meaning having only the zero vector in common.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $ \dim(V) + \dim(W) -\dim(V+W) =  \dim(V \cap W)$.

So we look at the cases individually: In the first case, $\dim(V)=2$, $\dim(W) = 2$ and $2 \leq \dim(V+W) \leq 4$. Therefore: $0 \leq \dim(V \cap W) \leq 2$.

In the second case, $\dim(V)=4$, $\dim(W) = 4$ and $4 \leq \dim(V+W) \leq 7$. Therefore: $1 \leq \dim(V \cap W) \leq 4$. So $\dim(V+W)$ cannot be zero.

Comment: Rambotutoring's argument for the 0568 problem does not exclude zero. Why can similar reasoning not apply to the 1268 problem?